# Does this message indicate that the hard drive has failed?

Tags: hard-drive, boot

So, I have a Dell PC from approximately 2009-2010, and I believe the hard drive has failed.

Here's what the screen says when it starts up:

```
AMIBIOS(c) 2009 American Megatrends, Inc.
BIOS Date: 05/26/10 18:15:43 Ver: A02
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 930 @ 2.80GHz Speed: 2.80GHz

Initializing USB Controllers .. Done.
9208MB OK
USB Device(s): 1 Keyboard, 2 Mice
Auto-Detecting AHCI PORT 0..ATAPI CDROM
Auto-Detecting AHCI PORT 2..IDE Hard Disk
SATA Port0 PLDS DVD+/-RW DH-16ABS PD11
SATA Port2 ST31500341AS CC4G
            S.M.A.R.T. Capable and Status BAD
Auto-detecting USB Mass Storage Devices ..
00 USB mass storage devices found and configured.

AHCI Port2 Device Error
Press F1 to Resume
```

Of course, if I actually press `F1`, nothing actually happens.

Does this indicate a hard drive failure, or are their other possible explanations?

(For the record - everything on the hard-drive is backed up to the cloud, so I'm not concerned about losing or recovering any data.)

One option is to purchase a new hard drive and attempt to repair it myself. However, if I manage to install the new drive and it STILL doesn't work, I won't have improved my situation, and will be out the cost of the hard drive. And I'll still have a 5+ year old computer.

Another option is to bring it to a local PC repairman who is much more likely to fix it successfully, but I'm not thrilled about giving a stranger unfettered access to my hard drive (which contains personal financial info, like tax returns).

So I guess my real question is... what's the best option?

And, is a computer of this age worth repairing?

Comment: No one else will be able to accurately determine whether the risk is worth it to you or not. If you are willing to post all of your financial details I suppose that someone could make a more educated guess, but it would still be your opinion that would matter.

Comment: "if I manage to install the new drive and it STILL doesn't work, I won't have improved my situation, and will be out the cost of the hard drive" This is why you hire a professional, to absorb the risks.  "I'm not thrilled about giving a stranger unfettered access to my hard drive" Pull the defective drive out before giving them the computer to install the new one. Regardless, there's no actual computer problem here - VTC.

Comment: "Is a [six years old computer] worth repairing?" Well, by the time my previous system gave up the ghost most likely due to power transients taking out the PSU, it was old enough that some parts were outright difficult to come by new. I think at that point it was just under ten years old. Sure, that system saw upgrades and components replacements over the years, but never any single major overhaul (the CPU was the same as when I initially built the system, for example). If you're happy with the system, and just unhappy that it doesn't boot, no need to buy a whole new PC just for a HDD.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I guess what I'm asking (poorly) is that based on the error - is it likely that the error is ONLY a hard-drive failure (in which case, a hard-drive replacement is likely to be successful), or likely to be a HD failure PLUS something else (or something different altogether)? Or, is there no way to tell from this error message?

Comment: Option based. But typically if its the hard drive, its a *simple* fix, and at worst, you can buy an enclosure for your drive. I've got 2007 era boxen that are in fairly active use, and I'm even looking at upgrading them to low end SSDs.

Answer (score 1):

The hard drive will run you about $50 if you get a regular HDD.

All you really have to do is try it. If it works with the hard drive, you install the Windows version you currently have, and you're done.

If it doesn't work, then you can find out what's wrong with it, by providing us with the details of what happens or simply by looking around for the symptoms.

It doesn't take but a few screws and two cables to replace a hard drive, so there is really no reason to take it to a computer shop in my opinion.

I say it's worth repairing.

Comment: John, Thanks for the response. So - when I bought it (back in 2009 or 2010) - it came with Windows 7 preinstalled. Last month - I upgraded it to Windows 10. (The upgrade was free, and it didn't ask for a "key" or anything like that. Anyway - I no longer have the original Windows 7 discs, or any sort of license/key/token. Any idea what the odds are that I can get Windows installed without having to purchase a new license?

Comment: Do you still have your Windows 7 product key on your computer?

Comment: @QMord - Yes - there's still a sticker on the back with what I assume is a Windows 7 product key. Thanks for the tip - I'd completely forgotten about that.

Comment: Just install Windows 10 from the .ISO it will automatically activate.  You don't need to know your Windows 7 product key.  Windows 10 currently won't even activate with it anyways.